# How to find all subgroups of a group in GAP

Tags: group-theory, gap

With the next group:

```
gap> G:=Group((1,2,3,4),(1,2));

Group([ (1,2,3,4), (1,2) ])

gap> Order(G);

24

gap> Elements(G);

[ (), (3,4), (2,3), (2,3,4), (2,4,3), (2,4), (1,2), (1,2)(3,4),
  (1,2,3), (1,2,3,4), (1,2,4,3), (1,2,4), (1,3,2), (1,3,4,2),
  (1,3), (1,3,4), (1,3)(2,4), (1,3,2,4), (1,4,3,2), (1,4,2),
  (1,4,3), (1,4), (1,4,2,3), (1,4)(2,3) ]
```

Is there any function to list the subgroups of G?
Thanks, and sorry if the question looks so easy, i'm a newbie in GAP.

Comment: Please see [How do I get the subgroups of my group?](http://www.gap-system.org/Faq/faq.html#7.7) from GAP F.A.Q

Comment: Also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/460727/ and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1368608/

Comment: Thanks Alexander , I could not find the information in the oficial website.

Comment: You're welcome! I am debating whether this should be closed as a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460727/computing-conjugacy-classes-of-subgroups-in-gap) or renamed to "How to find all subgroups of a group in GAP" and answered properly here...

Comment: Ok Alexander, I've renamed it now.

Comment: Alexander in order to this question, I've found the function "Subgroups()" in the package SONATA. This function give a list of subgroups of a group. Is it correct?

Comment: Great - that's why I tend to think that this question is needed here and should be answered properly:) Both `Subgroups` from SONATA and even `AllSubgroups` in GAP work only with toy examples. As soon as one tries them on larger groups, thee became very inefficient, and one should use `ConjugacyClassesSubgroups` or other functions listed in [F.A.Q.](http://www.gap-system.org/Faq/faq.html#7.7) This also promotes good way of thinking - don't ask GAP for more, if you need e.g. class representatives or normal subgroups only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32843/discussion-between-angel-blasco-and-alexander-konovalov).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One should think in terms of conjugacy classes of subgroups:

```
gap> G:=Group((1,2,3,4),(1,2));
Group([ (1,2,3,4), (1,2) ])
gap> cc:=ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(G);
[ Group( () )^G, Group( [ (1,3)(2,4) ] )^G, Group( [ (3,4) ] )^G, 
  Group( [ (2,4,3) ] )^G, Group( [ (1,4)(2,3), (1,3)(2,4) ] )^G, 
  Group( [ (3,4), (1,2)(3,4) ] )^G, Group( [ (1,3,2,4), (1,2)(3,4) ] )^G, 
  Group( [ (3,4), (2,4,3) ] )^G, Group( [ (1,4)(2,3), (1,3)(2,4), (3,4) ] )^G, 
  Group( [ (1,4)(2,3), (1,3)(2,4), (2,4,3) ] )^G, 
  Group( [ (1,4)(2,3), (1,3)(2,4), (2,4,3), (3,4) ] )^G ]
```

For example, `Group( [ (1,3)(2,4) ] )^G` means a conjugacy class of a subgroup `Group( [ (1,3)(2,4) ] )`. The 1st element of the returned list in this example is `Group( () )^G` - the conjugacy class of the trivial subgroup, but in general the order in which the classes are listed depends on the method chosen by GAP, so you should not rely on it being always the 1st.

Now take, for example, the 2nd conjugacy class from this list. It contains 3 subgroups:

```
gap> c:=cc[2];
Group( [ (1,3)(2,4) ] )^G
gap> Size(c);
3
```

We can use `Representative` to get the representative of the class

```
gap> Representative(c);
Group([ (1,3)(2,4) ])
```

and `AsList` to get all subgroups from this class:

```
gap> AsList(c);
[ Group([ (1,3)(2,4) ]), Group([ (1,4)(2,3) ]), Group([ (1,2)(3,4) ]) ]
```

GAP also has a function [`AllSubgroups`](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap39.html#X80399CD4870FFC4B) (since GAP 4.5), but **it is intended primarily for use in class for small examples, and quickly becomes inefficient for larger groups**. Instead of using `AllSubgroups` one should think algorithmically. Do you need all subgroups or only up to conjugacy? Do you want only normal subgroups, or maximal, or maybe of a particular order or isomorphism type? In this case, look at:

- [`NormalSubgroups`](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap39.html#X80237A847E24E6CF)
- [`IsomorphicSubgroups`](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap40.html#X83B417BE7C508DC4)
- [`RepresentativesPerfectSubgroups`](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap39.html#X7BA3484E7AE0A0E1)
- [`RepresentativesSimpleSubgroups`](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap39.html#X7BA3484E7AE0A0E1)
- [`ConjugacyClassesMaximalSubgroups`](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap39.html#X8486C25380853F9B)
- [`ConjugacyClassesPerfectSubgroups`](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap39.html#X7B2233D180DF77A1)

If only $p$-subgroups are needed, it is often faster to compute the subgroup lattice of the Sylow $p$-subgroup (see [`SylowSubgroup`](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap39.html#X7AA351308787544C)), and then use conjugation to find more, if it is not normal.

Furthermore, [`LatticeByCyclicExtension`](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap39.html#X86462A567DDBA6BC) and [`SubgroupsSolvableGroup`](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap39.html#X7AD7804A803910AC) accept optional arguments which allow to put restrictions on computed subgroups. In the latter case functions `SizeConsiderFunction` and `ExactSizeConsiderFunction` may be used.

For more advanced techniques, see also the Chapter ["Tables of Marks"](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap70.html) and in particular Section ["Accessing Subgroups via Tables of Marks"](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap70.html#X7FE9BE477A90199F) - but that will work only for groups whose tables are contained in the tables of marks library.

Further reading:

- [How do I get the subgroups of my group](http://www.gap-system.org/Faq/faq.html#7.7) from GAP F.A.Q.
- [Computing Conjugacy Classes of Subgroups in GAP](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/460727/)
- [$p$-subgroups in GAP](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1368608/)