# Is it possible to write a code that computes all the subgroups (up to isomorphism) of a finite Abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, direct-sum, gap

I am new to computational group theory. I am trying to find/write a program that computes the following:

**Input:** a finite abelian group $$G \cong \mathbb{Z}_{m_1} \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{m_{m_t}}=\langle(1,0, \ldots 0), (0,1, \ldots 0), \ldots, (0,0, \ldots 1)\rangle
,$$ where $m_i \mid m_{i+1}$ for $i=1, \ldots, t-1$.

**Output:**  **All** the subgroups of $G$ and identify which subgroups are isomorphic to each other.

I was wondering if such a package already exists. If not, what would be a good programming language to write it? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Sage is a standard reference for computational algebra, check out https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/groups/sage/groups/abelian_gps/abelian_group.html

Comment: Duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1569349/104041

Comment: I accidentally retracted my close vote.

Comment: @Shaun It is not an exact duplicate, because the linked post is about computing subgroups of an arbitrary finite group. I am not sure whether GAP has separate code for finite abelian groups. In Magma it is a separate function using an enumeration of possible Hermite normal forms to find the subgroups. Magma is not open source so I cannot provide a direct link to the code.

Comment: In GAP (I wrote that code), as of today, the only special code is for elementary abelian groups. Other abelian groups then are composed from these, using a more general method for solvable groups.

Comment: @ahulpke Thank you, could you tell me what the command is?

Comment: @ghc1997 It's `SubgroupsSolvableGroup` in the file `lib/grppclat.gi`